# Multiple NSOperation with the sane NSManagedObjectContext?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I have two or more different `Operation` subclasses, each of them performing a network request and storing the data in Core Data.
I added the operations to an `OperationQueue` as you can see in the code below.

I have 2 questions:

1 - Are these operations executed in sequence, or are they asynchronous?

2 - If they are asynchronous, passing the same `context` could be an issue?

```
    let opQueue = OperationQueue()
    opQueue.addOperation(NetworkRequest.init(context:managedObjectContext))
    opQueue.addOperation(NetworkRequest2.init(context:managedObjectContext))
    opQueue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
```

Thanks

Comment: if the maxConcurrent = 1, your operations should be executed in sequence. In that case, I think that using the same managedObjectContext is fine. You must be sure that all operation with your managedObejctContext are finished within that NSOperation.

Comment: Ah! Ok, so they are executed asyncrounsly right now.

Comment: Its actually crashing after few reiterations:  error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x60000005be70> was mutated while being enumerated. with userInfo (null)
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.

Comment: ah! Nevermind, solved with NSManagedObjectContext.init(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)